# Retrieve image captured before saving it to the app

Tags: android, android-camera

Being new to Android, I want to know how we can retrieve the image captured from the camera (which is being called by my application through intents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer from Sandy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7817685) is right but I would like to add more, that I tried to edit in his answer but couldn't so posting this

```
String path =   "File path"; 
File file = new File(path); 
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file ); 
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE ); 
intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri ); 
startActivityForResult( intent, 101 );
```

You can check the New Image Taken at the Path specified above in `onActivityResult()` method also Don't Forget to put `if() condition to check the resultCode is Ok or not`. like this,

```
if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
  //get Image back from the path like BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);            
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info.. i got it. can we go directly to the gallery in device and get photos..

Comment: @bharath yes ofcaurse you will need to call intent for with setType and setAction..you better ask new question for that so you can get more related answer for this,,you can also find many similar question in android just search "how to call android gallery intent to select image and video?"

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
String path =   "File path";
File file = new File(path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
```